# How to create a KPI in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

We have a KPI of 75% of all Manual tests should pass the first time. How can we get this information from VSTS?

We have tried looking for a widget for this. We have tried using the charts in test plans, but this only shows the current state of play for the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do it directly, you can build an extension to statistics programming with REST API.

An article about dashboard widget extension: [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=vsts)